# Map between Mordell-Weil group and Ext of (Mixed) Motives

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties, motives, motivic-cohomology

We know that the motivic cohomology of an abelian variety $A$ over a number field $k$ computes the Mordell-Weil group up to torsion, and so if we were to grant the existence and nice behaviour of mixed motives then we should have
$$A(k)\otimes \mathbb{Q}\cong \text{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{MM}_k}(1,h^1(A)(1))$$
(unless I got the indices wrong). My question how we can describe the map
$$A(k)\to  \text{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{MM}_k}(1,h^1(A)(1)),$$
by which I mean there should be a representative of the Ext class in terms of the section $x\in A(k)$.

Comment: As far as I understand these matters, the extension class you are interested in should be an extension of 1-motives. It appears that "everything is known" about 1-motives; you may try to read the book of Barbieri-Viale and Kahn. Yet the answer may be rather tautological.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko I'm sorry, but why "should it be" an extension of $1$-motives as opposed to mixed motives?

Comment: 1-motives form a very explicit and non-conjectural exact subcategory of conjectural mixed motives.

Comment: I think the idea should be that $\mathrm{Ext}^{1}(A,\mathbb{G}_{m})\otimes\mathbb{Q}\simeq\mathrm{Ext}^{1}_{\mathcal{MM}_{k}}(\mathbb{Q}(-1),h^{1}(A))\simeq\mathrm{Ext}^{1}_{\mathcal{MM}_{k}}(\mathbb{Q},h^{1}(A)(1))$, and $\mathrm{Pic}^{0}(A)\simeq\mathrm{Ext}^{1}(A,\mathbb{G}_{m})$. Note that this also gives $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{MM}_{k}}(\mathbb{Q},h^{2}(A)(1))\simeq\mathrm{NS}(A)_{\mathbb{Q}}$.